# Using Mapbox studio style and exported mbtiles to create web map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I used Mapbox Studio to create a style using a local tile source. I exported the source to get vector mbtiles.

Now how do I use these mbtiles and the style (which is still in Mapbox Studio) to actually host my slippy maps?

I can't host my data with Mapbox.

There are plenty of options to read mbtiles and serve maps but I can't figure out how to style those maps on the fly using my CartoCSS from Mapbox Studio.

Answer (score 3):

CartoCSS would need to be processed into a Mapnik stylesheet in order to be applied to your vector tiles. For serving and styling your tiles, I would recommend checking out [tilelive](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive) and [tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera).